# mongodb aggregate get last object from sub document that mutch a query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

We have the following set of documents stored in mongodb:

**Conversation record**:

```
{_id: "x", lang: "en", timestamp: "", ... }
```

Each conversation has many processes, each process has set of messages as child-document list.
**Process** record:

```
{_id: "y", conversationId: "x", name: "", timestamp: "", messages: [
    {
        "direction" : "out",
        "text" : "How can I help you?",
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-05-23T11:08:18.423Z"),
        "_id" : 3
    },
    {
        "direction" : "out",
        "text" : "Hello",
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-05-23T11:08:17.423Z"),
        "_id" : 1
    },
    {
        "direction" : "in",
        "text" : "Hi",
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-05-23T11:08:18.423Z"),
        "_id" : 2
    }
], completed: "true"}
```

I need to make `aggregate` query, and get list of conversations, while each conversation should have list of processes ordered by timestamp, and each process should have only the **last** message (**based on id field**) from both "in" and "out" directions.

We need to get something like this:

```
[
  {
    conversationId: "x",
    timestamp: "",
    processes: [
      {
        _id: "y",
        name: "",
        timestamp: "",
        lastInMessage: {
          "direction": "in",
          "text": "Hi",
          "timestamp": ISODate("2019-05-23T11:08:18.423Z"),
          "_id": 2
        },
        lastOutMessage: {
          "direction": "out",
          "text": "How can I help you?",
          "timestamp": ISODate("2019-05-23T11:08:18.423Z"),
          "_id": 3
        }
      },
      {
        _id: "y",
        name: "",
        ....
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The query I tried is:

```
conversation.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                timestamp: query.timestamp
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: "$conversationId",
                timestamp: "$timestamp",
                conversationId: "$conversationId"
            }
        },
        {
            "$lookup":
                {
                    "from": "processes",
                    "localField": "conversationId",
                    "foreignField": "conversationId",
                    "as": "process"
                }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: "$_id",
                timestamp: "$timestamp",
                // messages: "$process.messages",
                processes: "$process"
            }
        },
       // here I don't know what to do.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) to calculate min and max value of an array and use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to generate aggregates for all `process` values:

```
{
    $project: {
        _id: "$_id",
        timestamp: "$timestamp",
        processes: {
            $map: {
                input: "$processes",
                as: "process",
                in: {
                    _id: "$$process._id",
                    name: "$$process.name",
                    timestamp: "$$process.timestamp",
                    lastInMessage: {
                        $reduce: {
                            input: "$$process.messages",
                            initialValue: null,
                            in: {
                                $cond: [
                                    { $and: [ { $eq: [ "$$this.direction", "in" ] }, { $gt: [ "$$this.timestamp", "$$value.timestamp" ] } ] },
                                    "$$this",
                                    "$$value"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    lastOutMessage: {
                        $reduce: {
                            input: "$$process.messages",
                            initialValue: null,
                            in: {
                                $cond: [
                                    { $and: [ { $eq: [ "$$this.direction", "out" ] }, { $gt: [ "$$this.timestamp", "$$value.timestamp" ] } ] },
                                    "$$this",
                                    "$$value"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[MongoDB Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dVFcB3jOhHQ)

Comment: Thanks! I'm checking. Does `$$value.timestamp` should be `$$value._id`? I need to sort by id.

Comment: @user2503775 it can be, it's just to show you how you can apply your condition and compare current result with previous one

Comment: Thanks! It works perfect. Do you think map&reduce are heavy query? the other option is to get all messages from mongo, and then loop on the conversations.processes array and get the last message by simple js function. what is better?

Comment: I would prefer database side aggregation as you don't need to pull unnecessary data to your app

Comment: Thanks. How can I sort the processes itself by timestamp?

Comment: @user2503775 use $lookup with custom pipeline and use $sort as a last stage: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries